# Add keys to values that don't already have keys in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Given the fallowing array `$array`:

```
Array
 (
  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 267
        [location_id_keep] => 261
    )
  [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 266
        [location_id_keep] => 262
    )
  [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2669
        [1] => 2670
        [location_id_keep] => 2668
    )
  [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 266
        [1] => 2670
        [location_id_keep] => 2668
    )
  )
```

I want to add to the each arrays values that doesn't have the [`location_id_keep`] key the fallowing key: [`location_id_delete`] so that I will get this output:

```
Array

(

[1] => Array
    (
        [location_id_delete] => 267
        [location_id_keep] => 261
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [location_id_delete] => 266
        [location_id_keep] => 262
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [location_id_delete] => [2669, 2670]
        [location_id_keep] => 2668
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [location_id_delete] => [266, 2670]
        [location_id_keep] => 2668
    )
)
```

Is there any method to add keys inside array assigned to already existing values that doesn't have a key ?

Comment: How did you want to have the same key `location_id_delete`?

Comment: Your desired output is not valid; PHP arrays cannot have more than one element with the same key.

Comment: Its wrong `[location_id_delete] => 2669
        [location_id_delete] => 2670`  should be,for example, `[location_id_delete] => [2669,2670]`

Comment: Something like this [location_id_delete] => [2669, 2670] etc

Comment: I made the correction to my desired output.

Comment: If you create the first array, please include the code so that can be amended rather than having to do a second set of processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should works, but I suggest you shourld reconstruct the structure of your data. [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/51944517132313ae0df180b7287505d36207ad26)

```
foreach($arrays as &$array){
    if($array["location_id_keep"]){
        $temp_array["location_id_keep"] = $array["location_id_keep"];
        unset($array["location_id_keep"]);
    }
    $count = count($array);
    if($count == 1) {
        $temp_array["location_id_delete"] = current($array);
    }elseif($count > 1){
        $temp_array["location_id_delete"] = array_values($array);
    }
    $array = $temp_array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [**array_walk()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and [**array_filter()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). array_filter is to filtering the values who's key is number (you mean `location_id_delete` here).

```
$array = [[0 => 267, 'location_id_keep' => 261],[0 => 266, 'location_id_keep' => 262],[0 => 2669, 1 => 2670, 'location_id_keep' => 2668], [0 => 266, 1 => 2670, 'location_id_keep' => 2668]];

array_walk($array, function (&$val) {
    $val = [
       'location_id_delete' => array_filter($val, 'is_numeric', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY), 
       'location_id_keep' => $val['location_id_keep']
    ];
});

print_r($array);
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/TTePk).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the snippet,

```
array_walk($arr, function (&$v) {
    // keeping location_id_keep aside to perform operation of replacing keys
    $temp = array_diff_key($v, ['location_id_keep' => '']);
    if (!empty($temp)) {
        // getting the count of sub arrays other than location_id_keep
        $cnt = count($temp);
        foreach ($temp as $key => $value) {
            // if one record then directly assign data
            if ($cnt == 1) {
                $v['location_id_delete'] = $value;
            } else{ // assign multiple data in an arrat
                $v['location_id_delete'][] = $value;
            }
            // unset numeric index or other than location_id_keep
            unset($v[$key]);
        }
    }
});
```

[array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) — Apply a user-supplied function to every member of an array
[array_diff_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) — Computes the difference of arrays using keys for comparison

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/VdDXA)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [location_id_keep] => 261
            [location_id_delete] => 267
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [location_id_keep] => 262
            [location_id_delete] => 266
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [location_id_keep] => 2668
            [location_id_delete] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2669
                    [1] => 2670
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [location_id_keep] => 2668
            [location_id_delete] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 266
                    [1] => 2670
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will Works

```
  foreach($newArray as $key => $val){
            if(array_key_exists('location_id_keep',$val)){
                $array[$key]['location_id_keep'] = $val['location_id_keep'];
                unset($val['location_id_keep']);
            }
            $count = count($val);
            if($count>1){
                 $array[$key]['location_id_delete'] = implode(',',$val);
            }else{
                $array[$key]['location_id_delete'] = $val[0];
            }       
        }
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [location_id_keep] => 261
            [location_id_delete] => 267
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [location_id_keep] => 262
            [location_id_delete] => 266
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [location_id_keep] => 2668
            [location_id_delete] => 2669,2670
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [location_id_keep] => 2668
            [location_id_delete] => 266,2670
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Functional solution

```
foreach($arrays as &$array){
    // get numeric key items 
    $temp = array_filter($array, 'is_numeric',ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    // remove them from array and return under new key
    $array = array_diff($array, $temp) + ['location_id_delete'=>$temp];
}
```

[demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99ee9ab143e2e4cf599cb2da062de194bc3b1d11)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` with `implode` and `unset`

```
  foreach($a as $k => &$v){
    $location = $v['location_id_keep'];
    unset($v['location_id_keep']);
    $r[] = [
      'location_id_delete' => implode(',',$v), 
      'location_id_keep'   => $location
    ];
  }
```

Live example : https://3v4l.org/kqCVH